# Solar Cell Performance With Varying Incident Angle

Tags: power, solar-cell, solar-energy, space

I am trying to calculate the power generated from solar panels placed on the Moon. I have an equation for power generated at the beginning and end of life and have hit a snag in my brain.
If the solar array is on the 'equator' of the moon (I know that the moon is tilted slightly so lets pretend it isn't for sake of ease in this question), so the incident angle of the solar rays would be 0 and the power generated would be at a maximum.
$$
P_{BOL}=(flux)(solar cell efficiency)I_D\cos\theta
$$
$$
P_{BOL}=1386\times0.2\times0.77\times1=116.43
$$
So this is the best case and as the Moon rotates about its axis, \$\theta\$ increases and hence the power output decreases. Good.

Now my question is, what if the solar array is not placed on the equation, i.e. the best case scenario for it is where there is already an incident angle present (for this example I am saying the solar array is placed much closer to one of the poles).
Obviously you still have the change in \$\theta\$ with the rotation of the Moon, but you also have this offset \$\theta\$ which is there to start with - how do we account for this?

I was initially thinking that we take the original \$\theta\$ and only once the rotational \$\theta\$ becomes greater than it do we use that value, but I don't think that could possibly be right.

So I have come to the conclusion that the equation I started with will need to have two \$\cos\theta\$ values, one for the initial offset and the other for the rotation of the Moon. Am I correct in this thinking?

*Apologies for the very long winded question, I am not good at concise writing when I am trying to explain my thought process without the aid of diagrams. The values used in the equations are typical values as well. Any questions, please ask and I will try and clarify it.*

Comment: Although this is an interesting question, this feels more like a math/geometry question than electronics design. (I don't mean this in a bad way, I just think you might find more appropriate help in other SE)

Comment: Useful search term : "equatorial mount"

Comment: Not to be confused with "equestrian mount"

Comment: Solar irradiance is more like \$1365\:\frac{\textrm{W}}{\textrm{m}^2}\$. What is \$I_D\$? You already have watts in your equation. Dimensional analysis doesn't work out for me, yet.

Comment: @jonk \$I_D\$ is inherent degradation, I've used a typical value for this.

Comment: That is an Earth-based figure?

Comment: @jonk It is for losses during manufacturing and assembly, temperature losses and shadowing due to appendages - can vary from 0.49 - 0.88.

Comment: Thanks. That's clear. Are you aware of a report, just yesterday based upon the Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter: "Any long-term lunar structures would have to be built to withstand impacts from dust particles moving at 1,120 miles per hour." That is just for secondary kicked up dust impacts and doesn't include the \$50\:\frac{\textrm{km}}{\textrm{s}}\$ particle velocities that bedevil our LEO satellites already. And I have about 5 other important and quite different problems to mention.

Comment: I'm sure NASA has a few reports about solar panels outside Earth's environment. Have you found and read any? (I worked with a physicist involved in extending the lifetime of satellites in space and I have lots of horror stories about solar panels.)

Comment: If not , at the equator then with a classic Lambertian response you get two cosine products depending on the longitude and latitude or the angles they create with respect to the sun. $$
P_{BOL}=1.3kW/m^2* Area * (effic.)\cos\theta\cos\phi\
$$  The efficiency may not include all the spectrum of the sun is not a flat response, so 1kW/m^2 is more practical.

Comment: Surface and internal charge accumulation, low energy protons, cosmic rays, 'gunk' accumulation due to charged surfaces attracting crap, non-charged dust accumulation, temperature effects on efficiency, structural flexures due to temperature (Si has a low coefficient, but other parts may not), high energy protons and solar flares, direct and secondary impacts, etc. The entire EUMETSAT fleet of geostationary spacecraft, for example, experienced a permanent 3% degradation from a single solar flare event in 2003. And that's only a partial list in no particular order.

Comment: Does the \$I_D\$ term take into account the reduced wavelengths that are available.... the 1366 figure is ALL energy in all wavelengths. Or is it something else?

Comment: Since the sun is much larger than the moon, you never get cos[phi] = 0. The minimum effective phi will be about half a degree: with the 'no wobble' assumption in the OP, you can always see the sun at the poles.